# Zune & iTunes parallel - Better cover handling

Tags: itunes, ipod, zune, zune-software

I own a ZuneHD and manage my library with the Zune software so far. We recently bought an iPod which has to be synced with the same library now.

So far so good, I installed iTunes, pointed it at my files and syncing works as expected. But the whole cover handling is driving me crazy. iTunes doesn't show many of the covers the Zune software shows and can't find them in its own database. I suppose that's because my whole collection is ripped by the Zune software from audio CDs which seems to use it's own database to edit metatags.

So I only see the way to add the covers manually to iTunes. Is there any way to make this easier?